# Como unificar os resultados de count POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql, return, count

**Bom dia, eu preciso que essa query retorne o resultado unificado, diferente do que me retorna, alguém tem alguma ideia de como faz isso no Postgres?? fui até maio(mai) mas continua até o final dos meses, meu parâmetro $1 é ANO** .

```sql
RETURN QUERY SELECT DC.cod_descricao_status, DC.nome,
 
        (CASE WHEN TEMP.ano IS NULL THEN $1 ELSE TEMP.ano END) AS "ano",
        (CASE WHEN TEMP.jan IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TEMP.jan END) AS "jan",
        (CASE WHEN TEMP.fev IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TEMP.fev END) AS "fev",
        (CASE WHEN TEMP.mar IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TEMP.mar END) AS "mar",
        (CASE WHEN TEMP.abr IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TEMP.abr END) AS "abr",
        (CASE WHEN TEMP.mai IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TEMP.mai END) AS "mai"
FROM public.pla_descricao_status_tarefa AS DC  


        
        INNER JOIN
        
    (SELECT S.cod_descricao_status, D.nome,             EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.data_alteracao) AS "ano",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (S.data_alteracao)) = 1) THEN S.data_alteracao END) AS "jan",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (S.data_alteracao)) = 2) THEN S.data_alteracao END) AS "fev",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (S.data_alteracao)) = 3) THEN S.data_alteracao END) AS "mar",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (S.data_alteracao)) = 4) THEN S.data_alteracao END) AS "abr",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (S.data_alteracao)) = 5) THEN S.data_alteracao END) AS "mai",

    COUNT(S.data_alteracao) AS TOTAL
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (cod_descricao_status, cod_tarefa)cod_descricao_status, cod_tarefa, data_alteracao FROM public.pla_status_tarefa) AS S 
    INNER JOIN public.pla_tarefa AS T ON T.cod_tarefa = S.cod_tarefa
    INNER JOIN public.pla_descricao_status_tarefa AS D ON D.cod_descricao_status = S.cod_descricao_status
    WHERE (S.cod_descricao_status = 1 OR S.cod_descricao_status = 7 OR S.cod_descricao_status = 4) AND T.custo_executante LIKE CONCAT($2,'%') AND T.custo_executante NOT LIKE '101'
    AND T.flg_excluido = '0'
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.data_alteracao) = $1
    AND T.cod_tarefa IN (SELECT S1.cod_tarefa FROM public.pla_status_tarefa AS S1 WHERE S1.cod_descricao_status = 1)
    GROUP BY S.cod_descricao_status, D.nome, S.data_alteracao)
    AS TEMP ON DC.cod_descricao_status = TEMP.cod_descricao_status
    WHERE DC.cod_descricao_status = 1 OR DC.cod_descricao_status = 7 OR DC.cod_descricao_status = 4;
    END;
```

**ele me retorna assim :**

(1,"ENV - Enviado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

(1,"ENV - Enviado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

(1,"ENV - Enviado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

(4,"CAN - Cancelado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

(4,"CAN - Cancelado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

(4,"CAN - Cancelado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

(7,"FIN - Finalizado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)

(7,"FIN - Finalizado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)

(7,"FIN - Finalizado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)

(7,"FIN - Finalizado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)

**eu quero unificalos:**

(1,"ENV - Enviado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0)

(4,"CAN - Cancelado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0)

(7,"FIN - Finalizado",2020,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0)

**Desde já agradeço!**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visto que o objetivo é:

> Unificar os resultados de count

Visto que sua consulta já está resultando nas informações parciais que você precisa, basta realizar o agrupamento deste resultado parcial.

Uma possibilidade é considerar o resultado da sua consulta já existente como se fosse uma tabela, a qual chamarei de **r** lembrando da palavra resultado:

```
select cod_descricao_status, nome, ano, sum(jan) as janeiro, sum(fev) as fevereiro, sum(mar) as marco, sum(abr) as abril
  from (
    //Sua consulta original entra aqui
  ) as r
  group by r.ano, r.cod_descricao_status, r.nome
  order by r.ano, r.cod_descricao_status, r.nome
```

Não realizei análise da sua consulta pra verificar se existem melhorias a serem realizadas. Observei apenas o que pode ser feito para obter o resultado esperado.

Comment: Bom dia, e como ficaria no caso? pois tentei empregar aqui, mas não deu muito certo ..

Comment: Veja se o exemplo disponibilizado no Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/77ff7/4) auxiliar no entendimento.

Comment: Mas no caso minha tabela não possui uma escala por mês no caso:

cod_status| cod_tarefa| cod_usuario|  cod_usuario_alocado| cod_descricao_status|data_prevista_termino| obs   | data_alteracao | flg_excluido|
      55      |  26  |       99     |                 71      |       1  |  NULL            | NULL | "2018-04-05 10:09:02" | false         |

Comment: Sim, fiz a consulta considerando que seu trecho `COUNT(CASE WHEN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (S.data_alteracao)) = 1) THEN S.data_alteracao END) AS "jan",` está gerando a informação. Você pode produzir um ambiente de simulação no Fiddle? Nos fornece a url para podermos simular a consulta.  Busque melhorar sua pergunta, pois com a quantidade de votos negativa, corre o risco de ser fechada. Tente simplificar a consulta para facilitar o entendimento. No exemplo que fiz no Fiddle, considerei que você com sua consulta original já está obtendo o resultado que você menciona no corpo da sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou aqui, agradeço pela atenção!!